# PHP store array into seperate column

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

Currently I have an array:

```
$movie_seat = "seat1, seat2, seat3, seat4";

foreach($movie_seat as $keys =>$values)
        {
        $movie_id = $values["movie_id"];
        $movie_seats = $values["movie_seats"];

            $query = "INSERT INTO `testing` (`movie_id`,`movie_seat`) VALUES ('$movie_id ','$movie_seats')" ;

            $addmoviequery = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            if(!$addmoviequery){
                die("QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($conn));

            }
```

from the array, i will get the following result stored in database.It will store the whole array into the column movie_seat.

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| movie_id        | movie_seat                    |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| movie01         | seat1, seat2, seat3           |
| movie02         | seat5,seat6                   |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+
```

however, I would like record into database for different column

**The result i want:**

```
 +-----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
 | movie_id        | seat1 | seat2 | seat3 | seat4 | seat5 | seat6 |
 +-----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
 | movie01         | booked|booked |booked |       |       |       |
 | movie02         |       |       |       |       |booked |booked |
 +-----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried to use **explode** function but it will show

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\

Comment: Firstly in `foreach` use `$movie_seat` - not `movie_seat`.

Comment: yah..I missed out the $..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple errors in what you're doing.

```
$movie_seat = "seat1, seat2, seat3, seat4";
```

**This is not an `array`**. This is a `string`.

You have to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into an array, like this:

```
$seats = explode(",", $movie_seat);
```

This will create an `array` of strings called `$seats` where `$seats[0]` is equal to "seat1", etc...

Then you need to use your `foreach` using the new array that you created, not the old variable. Like this:

```
foreach($seats as $key => $value)
{
    //Your code goes here, 
    //First iteration should give you $key = 0, $value = "seat1", etc...
}
```